# InterfaceImp constract defined success，but interface function called failed

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to call a interface function for testing, but it can't work.

> Here is my test contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface InterfaceTest{
    function testInterface() external pure returns(uint);
}

contract TestContract {   

    InterfaceTest _inter;  

    function test2(address _addr) public returns(uint) {
        _inter = InterfaceTest(_addr);
        return 2;
    }

    function test4() public view returns(uint) {
        uint t = _inter.testInterface();
        return t;
    }
}
```

> And here is the implement:

```
interface InterfaceTest{
    function testInterface() external pure returns(uint);
}

contract InterfaceContract is InterfaceTest {
    function testInterface() external pure returns(uint) {
        return 9;
    }
}
```

I deployed them with truffle(4.1.14) and Ganache, the `test2()` function work well and return 2, but when I tried to call `test4()`, it said `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`, is there any Error in my code?

---

There is an interesting error I found:

```
function test2(address _addr) public {
    _interAddr = _addr;
}

function test22() public view returns(address) {
    return _interAddr;
}

function test222(address _addr) public view returns(bool) {
    if (_addr == _interAddr){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

First I set the `_interAddr`, and then I get it, but the TWO address are different, what looks like set `0x1d77078832a0f88c6e064cc5e4df88b83d3dd8ca` and get `0x1d77078832a0f8eca804a4989f812d2e80000000`. in `test222`, the last numbers have no effect to the result, my contract always return true.

Does anyone have the same error?

---

Finally I resolved. If you want to set an `address`, you must enclose address in `""`, what a stupid mistake. 
This problem has been solved, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help you**

```
contract TestContract{   

    InterfaceTest _inter;
    InterfaceContract ts = new InterfaceContract();

    function test2(address _addr) public returns(uint) {
        _inter = InterfaceTest(_addr);
        return 2;
    }


    function test4()public view returns(uint)  {
        uint t = ts.testInterface();
        return t;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you first.  The two contracts are in different .sol file, so just declare a 'InterfaceContract' instance will cause an error.

Comment: If both `.sol` files are different then you can import 'InterfaceContract' sol file in your 'TestContract' sol file and then create 'InterfaceContract' instance will work fine.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you, well, actually that seems not an 'interface' solution. If I want to interact with a deployed contract  or  extend it, it's impossible to import a new contract.    Thank you anyway.